# In Scala how to implicitly invoke a type classes knowing only it's super type?

Tags: scala

How can I find the right implicit `CommandHandler` type class by knowing only it's super class ?

In MainRunner class you can see the following code requires me to implement `AllCommandHandler` type class which does pattern matching on all the types. Is there a way I can find the right type class for the super type `UserCommand` without implementing a `AllCommandsHandler` ?

```
val command: UserCommand = CreateUser("userId2")
CommandHandlerRunner.processCommand(command)
```

The reason I need this is because some parts of my code get a `List[UserCommand]` which either come from database or get generated after validating an input command.

My code

```
import annotation.implicitNotFound

@implicitNotFound("No member of type class CommandHandler in scope for ${C}")
trait CommandHandler[C <: UserCommand] {
  def processCommand(command: C)

}

trait Command

sealed trait UserCommand

case class CreateUser(id: String) extends UserCommand

case class UpdatePassword(id: String, password: String) extends UserCommand

object CommandHandler {

  implicit object CreateUserCommandHandler extends CommandHandler[CreateUser] {
    override def processCommand(command: CreateUser) = println(command)
  }

  implicit object UpdateUserPasswordCommandHandler extends CommandHandler[UpdatePassword] {
    override def processCommand(command: UpdatePassword) = println(command)
  }

  //I have to do this which is ugly. Is there a way I can invoke the right CommandHandler without doing the following ?
  implicit object AllCommandsHandler extends CommandHandler[UserCommand] {
    override def processCommand(command: UserCommand) = command match {
      case command: CreateUser =>
        CommandHandlerRunner.processCommand(command)
      case command: UpdatePassword =>
        CommandHandlerRunner.processCommand(command)
      case _ =>
        sys.error("CommandHandler not found.")
    }
  }
}

object CommandHandlerRunner {

  def processCommand[C <: UserCommand](command: C)(implicit commandHandler: CommandHandler[C]) =
    commandHandler.processCommand(command)
}

object MainRunner extends App {
  CommandHandlerRunner.processCommand(CreateUser("userId1"))
  CommandHandlerRunner.processCommand(UpdatePassword("userId1", "newPassword"))

  //In my application in certain situation I get a List[UserCommand] (database query) and I want to invoke processCommand their relevant
  //handlers. How do I get this to work ?
  val command: UserCommand = CreateUser("userId2")
  CommandHandlerRunner.processCommand(command)
}
```

Comment: If `UserCommand` was a sealed trait, this should be possible using shapeless.

Comment: Yes it is a `sealed trait`. i've updated the code. I'm going to try read up on shapeless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `CommandHandler` derivation for `UserCommand` below works because you can represent a `UserCommand` as either a `CreateUser` or a `UpdatePassword` (that is way it is important that `UserCommand` is `sealed`).

- In shapeless a generic representation from `UserCommand` is then `CreateUser :+: UpdatePassword :+: CNil`.
- The `cnilCommandHandler` and `coproductConsCommandHandler` make it possible to get a `CommandHandler` instance for this generic representation.
- `genericCommandHandler` uses the instance from this generic representation to give you an instance for `UserCommand` (using `Generic[UserCommand]`).

---

Dropping the upper type bound from `CommandHandler` (the `<: UserCommand`) :

```
import shapeless._

trait CommandHandler[C] {
  def processCommand(command: C): Unit
}

object CommandHandler {
  // make it possible to derive a CommandHandler instance for sealed traits 
  // like UserCommand using shapeless Coproduct and Generic

  implicit val cnilCommandHandler: CommandHandler[CNil] = 
    new CommandHandler[CNil] {
      override def processCommand(t: CNil): Unit = ()
    }

  implicit def coproductConsCommandHandler[L, R <: Coproduct](implicit 
    lch: CommandHandler[L], 
    rch: CommandHandler[R]
  ): CommandHandler[L :+: R] = 
    new CommandHandler[L :+: R] {
      override def processCommand(t: L :+: R): Unit = t match {
        case Inl(l) => lch.processCommand(l)
        case Inr(r) => rch.processCommand(r)
      }
    }

  implicit def genericCommandHandler[A, G](implicit 
    gen: Generic.Aux[A, G],
    cch: Lazy[CommandHandler[G]]
  ): CommandHandler[A] =
    new CommandHandler[A] {
      def processCommand(a: A): Unit = cch.value.processCommand(gen.to(a))
    }
}
```

Now we can use your `UserCommand` :

```
sealed trait UserCommand
final case class CreateUser(id: String) extends UserCommand
final case class UpdatePassword(id: String, password: String) extends UserCommand

object UserCommand {
  implicit val createUserCommandHandler: CommandHandler[CreateUser] =
    new CommandHandler[CreateUser] {
      override def processCommand(command: CreateUser) = println(command)
    }

  implicit val updateUserPasswordCommandHandler: CommandHandler[UpdatePassword] =
    new CommandHandler[UpdatePassword] {
      override def processCommand(command: UpdatePassword) = println(command)
    }
}
```

... with your `CommandHandlerRunner`, even if the type is `UserCommand` :

```
object CommandHandlerRunner {
  def processCommand[C](command: C)(implicit commandHandler: CommandHandler[C]) =
    commandHandler.processCommand(command)
}

val cmd1: UserCommand = CreateUser("foo")
val cmd2: UserCommand = UpdatePassword("id", "open sesame")

CommandHandlerRunner.processCommand(cmd)
// CreateUser(foo)

List(cmd1, cmd2).foreach(CommandHandlerRunner.processCommand[UserCommand] _)
// CreateUser(foo)
// UpdatePassword(id,open sesame)
```

This may have been more code than you `AllCommandHandler`, but if you now created a `DBCommand` as follows :

```
sealed trait DBCommand
final case class Get(id: Int) extends DBCommand
final case class Save[A](a: A) extends DBCommand
```

And created `CommandHandler` instances for `Get` and `Save`, you would also get a `CommandHandler[DBCommand]`.

Comment: Wow! This is just wow! ... Wizardry lol! Thank you so much.  I will have to understand the theory behind this but wow !! Wish I could upvote this more the ones.

Comment: Wizardry is indeed a word to describe the things you can do with Shapeless, but indeed it takes time for these things to make some sense ... and even then it still feels like magic ;-)

Comment: In my question I regret not putting the `state:S` parameter in the function `processCommand` the actual function is `def processCommand(command: C, state: S): S`. I'm trying to fill in the blanks in your code but I don't know what to do in `coproductConsCommandHandler` & `genericCommandHandler` to add `S: State`

Comment: @hajime You should be able to pass the `state` from one `processCommand` to the next.  For `cnilCommandHandler` it would depend on the type `S`, possibly just `processCommand(t: CNil, state: S): S = state`.

Comment: do all the classes `CommandHandler.scala `, `UserCommand.scala `, `MainTest.scala` MainTest.scala being the one calling `CommandHandlerRunner.processCommand(cmd)` must be in the same class file ? Because I'm trying to put them in their own different class files and it cannot find the generic type `UserCommand`. I've also tried importing the `CommandHandler` object into the `MainTest` but it cannot find the implicit for `UserCommand`

Comment: You probably need to `import shapeless._` there too.

Comment: I've tired importing and a few others things. But something is missing ... I've push it to github please look if you have a moment. [github/shapeless-type-class-generic](https://github.com/hajime-moto/shapeless-type-class-generic)

Comment: @hajime Don't have the time at the moment, I will take a look tomorrow