# Creating a type class instance for a sealed trait

Tags: scala, typeclass

Say I have a 'wide' sealed class hierarchy:

```
sealed trait Alphabet
case class A(word: String) extends Alphabet
...
case class Z(word: String) extends Alphabet
```

And say I have a type class instance defined for each child class in the hierarchy:

```
trait SwearWordFinder[T <: Alphabet] {
  def isSwearWord(x: T): Boolean
}

val swearWordFinderA = new SwearWordFinder[A] { ... }
...
val swearWordFinderZ = new SwearWordFinder[Z] { ... }
```

Is there a way I can define a type class instance for the `Alphabet` trait itself without having to implement it by pattern matching (as below)?

```
def isSwearWord(x: Alphabet): Boolean = x match {
  case a: A => swearWordFinderA.isSwearWord(a)
  ...
  case z: Z => swearWordFinderZ.isSwearWord(z)
}
```

Comment: You can have a look at this article: http://www.cakesolutions.net/teamblogs/ways-to-pattern-match-generic-types-in-scala

Comment: You can use shapeless' `Coproduct` to derive an `SwearWordFinder` instance for `Alphabet`. I did something similar in [this answer to another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37815926/in-scala-how-to-implicitly-invoke-a-type-classes-knowing-only-its-super-type/37817368#37817368). You do have to look out for the SI-7046 Scala compiler issue if you go this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can represent `Alphabet` as a Shapeless `Coproduct` of `A :+: B :+: ... :+: Z :+: CNil`, so if you have `SwearWordFinder` instances for `A`, `B`, ... and define instances for `CNil` and `:+:` you can get a `SwearWordFinder[Alphabet]` using its generic representation.

```
import shapeless._

trait SwearWordFinder[T] {
  def isSwearWord(x: T): Boolean
}

object SwearWordFinder extends SwearWordFinder0 {
  implicit def apply[T](implicit swf: SwearWordFinder[T]): SwearWordFinder[T] = swf

  implicit val cnilSwearWordFinder: SwearWordFinder[CNil] = 
    new SwearWordFinder[CNil] {
      def isSwearWord(t: CNil): Boolean = false
    }

  implicit def coproductConsSwearWordFinder[L, R <: Coproduct](implicit 
    lSwf: SwearWordFinder[L], 
    rSwf: SwearWordFinder[R]
  ): SwearWordFinder[L :+: R] = 
    new SwearWordFinder[L :+: R] {
      def isSwearWord(t: L :+: R): Boolean = 
        t.eliminate(lSwf.isSwearWord, rSwf.isSwearWord)
    }
}

trait SwearWordFinder0 {
  implicit def genericSwearWordFinder[T, G](implicit 
    gen: Generic.Aux[T, G],
    swf: Lazy[SwearWordFinder[G]]
  ): SwearWordFinder[T] =
    new SwearWordFinder[T] {
      def isSwearWord(t: T): Boolean = swf.value.isSwearWord(gen.to(t))
    }
}
```

Now some instances for our letters :

```
sealed trait Alphabet extends Product with Serializable

object Alphabet {
  final case class A(word: String) extends Alphabet
  final case class Z(word: String) extends Alphabet
}

implicit val swfA = new SwearWordFinder[Alphabet.A] {
  def isSwearWord(a: Alphabet.A) = a.word == "apple"
}

implicit val swfZ = new SwearWordFinder[Alphabet.Z] {
  def isSwearWord(z: Alphabet.Z) = z.word == "zebra"
}
```

And now we can get a `SwearWordFinder[Alphabet]` :

```
def isBadWord[T](t: T)(implicit swfT: SwearWordFinder[T]): Boolean = 
  swfT.isSwearWord(t)

val a1: Alphabet = Alphabet.A("apple")
val z2: Alphabet = Alphabet.Z("zorro")
val z3: Alphabet = Alphabet.Z("zebra")

isBadWord(a1) // true
isBadWord(z2) // false
isBadWord(z3) // true
```

Like I mentioned in my comment: beware of [SI-7046](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7046). Your `Alphabet` AST needs to be in a project on which the project with `SwearWordFinder` depends or in a package which will be compiled before the package with the type class derivation for `Alphabet`.